# YOLOv7 compare pre-trained and finetuned models

Tags: yolo

I have done some fine tuning on YOLOv7 (with only 4 classes which are present in 80 classes from coco dataset). So I wanted to compare the performance of the model without being finetuned and after the finetuning.

I could run the 'test.py' command for my fine-tuned mode, but for the pre-trained model I get this error (when running the following command:

`python3 test.py --data "data/custom.yaml" --img 640 --batch 32 --conf 0.001 --iou 0.65 --device      0 --weights yolov7.pt --save-txt`

):

`Class      Images      Labels           P           R      mAP@.5  mAP@.5:.95:  24%|███          | 4/17 [00:04<00:14,  1.15s/it] Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/caa-stage/yolov7/test.py", line 314, in <module>     test(opt.data,   File "/home/yolov7/test.py", line 184, in test     confusion_matrix.process_batch(predn, torch.cat((labels[:, 0:1], tbox), 1))   File "/home/yolov7/utils/metrics.py", line 148, in process_batch     self.matrix[gc, detection_classes[m1[j]]] += 1  # correct IndexError: index 16 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5`

```
Have sombedu tried to compare these 2 results? ( I think it is possible by running detect.py with finetuned and pretrained weights and than establish the metrics, but I couldn't find any code for this).

Thank you in advance!
```

Answer (score 0):

delete " " from data/custom_data and replace batch by --batch-size.

```
!python test.py --data data/custom_data.yaml --img 640 --batch-size 4 --conf 0.001 --iou 0.65 --weights best.pt --name yolov7_e6_1280_val
```